# Auto increment applicationIconBadgeNumber when application quits

Tags: iphone

Programmers, I am new to objective C.

I am working on local notifications task and my task is that when user quits the applications and he doesn't run application again, suppose for one day, then the app icon badge number should auto increment to one. If it doesn't run for 48 hours, then it should increment and become 2 (means I have to repeat notification) and so on.

I am using local notifications for that. This how I am doing it:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    [self launchNotification];
}


-(void)launchNotification
{
    NSDate *todaydate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *firedates = [todaydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:10.0];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = firedates;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit |     NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)
                                                   fromDate:firedates];

    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]+10];

    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    //NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    //localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = +1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
}
```

I am working from long time and finding no way out.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I guess you cannot do this as a local notification cannot fire another notification in itself. You'll need a **piece of your code** to run and fire a new notification. If your application is not running (foreground or background), that **piece of your code** won't run.

Comment: actualy i dont want to display an alert or message at notification repeat what i want that after every repeat of notification the app icon badge no. should incrment to one, as u know we can repeat notifications, so what i want to do is to increment app icon badge no. at every repeat of notification.

Comment: n can u tell me how to repeat notification after every 10 seconds please.